# JavaFX progress indicator in a new window won't "spin"

Tags: java, javafx, window, progress, indicator

I made login screen and now I must do some background work that takes about 8-10seconds and I made new window with the progress indicator (indeterminate) but it just pop's out and it's static (not spinning), I assume I'm doing something wrong with the thread part, here is the code :

```
Task<Boolean> loginTask = new Task<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        protected Boolean call() throws Exception {
            return true;
        }
    };

    loginTask.setOnRunning(e -> {

           //background task(collecting data)

    });
```

And after this I did this :

```
 Thread thread = new Thread(loginTask);
    thread.setDaemon(true);
    thread.start();

    //progress indicator window
    Parent p = null;
    try {
        p = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/fxml/loginLoader.fxml"));
        p.setVisible(true);
        Scene scene = new Scene(p);
        Stage wndw = new Stage();
        this.loadingStage=wndw;
        wndw.setTitle("Loading data... Please wait.");
        wndw.setScene(scene);
        wndw.show();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

And it pop's out but it's static :

[image]

What I need to do to make progress indicator to spin?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're monopolizing the *JavaFX Application Thread* which means it can't update the UI, thus the `ProgressIndicator` does not animate.

```java
Task<Boolean> loginTask = new Task<Boolean>() {
    @Override
    protected Boolean call() throws Exception {
        return true;
    }
};

loginTask.setOnRunning(e -> {
    //background task(collecting data)
});
```

Your comment suggests you're doing the actual work in the `onRunning` handler which is not the correct way to use a `Task`. That handler is invoked on the FX thread when the `Task` enters the `RUNNING` state; it's meant as a callback where you can, for example, update the UI to indicate the change in status. The actual work of the task should be done in the `call()` method which is invoked on the background thread.